# Tapestry Read Docusign Connect Message

Tags: tapestry, docusignapi

I've set up Docusign to send a post request to tapestry once the envelope is completed. But in tapestry I cannot read the message. In Docusign Connect log this is what I see:

Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx :: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx :: Error - Unable to connect to the remote server; A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I've tried @Inject Request, and @Inject HttpServletRequest, using onActivate and doPost, but can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you actually read the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using DocuSign Connect, you don't need to do anything in the receiving application to explicitly acknowledge the Connect POST and respond to Connect.  Connect simply relies on basic HTTP protocol semantics -- i.e., it sends a Request to the endpoint (URL) you specify in the Connect configuration settings, and if that web server successfully receives the message, then it will automatically send a response back to Connect (i.e., per basic HTTP request-response protocol).

This error in DocuSign Connect simply means that the message Connect is sending to your endpoint is not actually reaching your endpoint. I'd suggest that you check the following:

- Is the URL that you specify as the receiving endpoint a valid URL?
- Is the receiving endpoint behind a firewall?  If so, have you done what's necessary to allow Connect messages to pass through the firewall?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's an https address, I'm guessing I need to take care of some configuration